# Why do I get 'The code editor does not support the Java runtime' for my AWS Lambda function?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

When I am trying to select Java 8 as the runtime for my AWS Lambda function, it shows:

> The code editor does not support the Java 8 runtime.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-java.html), the inline editor is not supported for the Java runtime on AWS Lambda.

> Since **Java is a compiled language**, you **can't view or edit the source code in the Lambda console**, but you can modify its configuration, invoke it, and configure triggers.

Answer (score 4):

You code your Lambda logic by using the AWS Lambda Java runtime API in a Java IDE such as IntelliJ and then build the JAR file. You then upload the JAR file using the the Lambda console. Once you deploy the JAR, you can run the Lambda function like you can when you create the Lambda function in other programming languages.

To learn how to build Lambda functions using the AWS Lambda runtime API (that invokes other AWS Services such as Amazon DynamoDB), see this development tutorial:

[Creating scheduled events to invoke Lambda functions](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/master/javav2/usecases/creating_scheduled_events)

This walks you through the process step by step - including how to configure the required IAM roles.